# script that checks text field do not work with chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a form and java script that checks if text filed was not empty. problem is, code works with IE and Firefox but do not work with chrome.

```
<form action="editor.php?id=<?=$id_book?>" method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="return check_form(this)" >
  <script language="javascript">
    function check()
    {
      if ((document.all.title.value==""))
      { 
        alert("Отсутствует название книги!"); 
      }

      if ((document.all.price.value==""))
      {
        alert("Отсутствует цена книги!"); 
      }

      if ((document.all.descrip.value==""))
      { 
        alert("Отсутствует описание книги!"); 
      }
      else
      {
        document.all.form1.submit();
      }
    }
  </script>
  <div class="list-group"> 
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><div class="inp_width">Название:</div></span>
      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="<?=$value['title']?>">
    </div><br />  

    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><div class="inp_width">Цена:</div></span>
      <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" value="<?=$value['price']?>">
    </div><br />

    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><div class="inp_width">Описание</div></span>       
      <textarea type="text" name="descrip" class="myform-control"  rows="5"><?=$value['descrip']?></textarea>
    </div><br />

    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="check()">Редактировать</button>
   </form>
 </div>
```

any ideas? More problem is that if I have just one filed check in chrome, scripts works fine. Submit button do not work only if I need to check several fields.

UPDATE: sorry guys... everything works fine... copy-paste will kill me... type button should be "Submit" instead of "button"... next time I'll should be more careful coping code:)

Comment: I have reformatted your code so that it becomes readable. Please do it yourself next time.

Comment: As you can see better now, [your code is not Valid](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input): The `script` element needs a `type` attribute (HTML4) or the `language` attribute must be removed (HTML5); a `div` element is not allowed in a `span` element; you start the `div` element, but end the `form` element before you end the `div` element. And as for PHP, the `foreach` for the `endforeach` is missing (I made sure that I did not remove it accidentally).

Comment: foreach was removed, just to make code smaller. Thank you for editing.

Comment: For next time, read [Secrets of the Browser Developer Tools](http://devtoolsecrets.com/). “Does not work” is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Your IF statements look incorrect. Only the last IF statement will stop the submit from happening, as that is the only call that the "else" step is associated with. For javascript please try the following format:

```
if (condition1)
  {
   code to be executed if condition1 is true
  }
else if (condition2)
  {
  code to be executed if condition2 is true
  }
else
  {
  code to be executed if neither condition1 nor condition2 is true
  }
```

additionally, if you want to check multiple values and if any of the values don't exist you should try some sort of flag. Example:

```
If (document.all.title.value==""){
    message += "Title is missing";
}
If (document.all.price.value==""){
    message += "Price is missing";
}

If (message == ""){
     document.all.form1.submit();
}else{
    alert(message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Markup errors aside (see my comment), [`document.all` is IE/MSHTML-proprietary and now deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for some reason Mozilla adopted it a few years ago).  Your code should look as follows when [standards-compliant](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element):

```
<form … onsubmit="return check_form(this)">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function check_form (form)
    {
      var elements = form.elements;

      if (elements["title"].value == "")
      { 
        window.alert("Отсутствует название книги!"); 
        return false;
      }

      if (elements["price"].value == "")
      {
        window.alert("Отсутствует цена книги!"); 
        return false;
      }

      if (elements["descrip"].value == "")
      { 
        window.alert("Отсутствует описание книги!");
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
  …
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Редактировать</button>
</form>
```

Note that the function returns `false` if there is an error, preventing the form from being submitted because the return value is returned to the `onsubmit` event handler (which I presume was the intention; you called, but did not define the `check()` function there).  You should not bother the user with several `alert()`s if there are several errors, but at most collect the error messages for one `alert()`. You can use an `Array` of `string` values for that.

However, given that new Firefox versions prevent the user from seeing the document while the `alert()` is displayed, you should avoid `alert()` and display the error messages in the document instead.  A common approach is to highlight the erroneous fields using scripted CSS, and put the message that says what is wrong with the particular field either in a box for the entire form or next to the offending control. Also consider [HTML5 form validation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#client-side-form-validation).